# AWS - RDS database connection returns no error but a white page

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo

I am trying to connect my EC2 instances to a RDS mysql database.
In my DB class I do this:

```
private function __construct() {

  $dbhost = "xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
  $dbport = "3306";
  $dbname = "mydatabase";
  $dsn = "mysql:host={$dbhost};port={$dbport};dbname={$dbname}";
  $username = "myUsername";
  $password = "myPassword";

    try {
           $this->_pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
           $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
           $this->_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I tried to query the database I don't get any error but a white screen even though I turned the error reporting on:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

The inbound traffic on the security group is wide open:
[image]

and both the RDS and the EC2 instance are on the same VPC (the default one).

Please note the code is working with my current database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the connection but my query was returning rows that had a single quote (ie. Men’s) so that caused the problem to json encode. I fixed it adding  `SET NAMES utf8`:

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password,
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```